# Why does replacing NaNs of a matrix not work with k(k==NaN) = SomeNumber , where k is the matrix to be operated

Tags: matlab

Given a matrix:-

```
k = [1   2   3  ;
     4   5   6  ;
     7   8  NaN];
```

If I want to replace a number, say 2, with 0, I can use this: `k(k==2) = 0` . It works correctly and gives the following expected answer:-

```
k =

     1     0     3
     4     5     6
     7     8   NaN
```

But why does this not work if I try to replace `NaN`, i.e. `k(k==NaN) = 0` gives this:

```
k =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8   NaN
```

Although I am able to achieve the desired result using: `k(isnan(k))=0`. But why does the first approach not work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `NaN==NaN` is `0`.

Not a number is equal to not a number? Not really, they are not numbers, but not necessarily the same thing. This is by design.

Is `0/0 == Inf-Inf` ? Definetly not. Both are `NaN` though.

[Read more here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/infinity-and-nan.html)

Comment: Also as by the mentioned link, `NaN ~= NaN` gives `1` which seems weird at first sight!! But now it makes sense. Thanks! 

Comment: See also the [More About](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html#moreabout) section of the documentation for `NaN`.

Comment: Lesson learned. `NaN == NaN` is implementation undefined.  Always use `isnan` for checking for `NaN`.