# Matlab: Replace NaN element values by value of the precious row

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace

I'm trying to replace all my matrix's NaN values by the value of the element in the previous row. How can I do that? This is what I tried (for the first column only) but somehow it doesn't work...

```
for i=1:1935 %number of rows
if RSPB0916v05NEW5(i,1)==NaN  
    RSPB0916v05NEW5(i,1) = RSPB0916v05NEW5((i-1),1) 
end
end
```

Thanks so much for your help, much appreciated!

Best,

Michael

Comment: Cells are indexed with curly brackets `{}`. Also, think what happens when `i=1`

Comment: Thanks, Ander. But I'm working with a matrix. If I use curly brackets it says: 
    Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
Thanks for the hint though regarding i=1

Comment: The word "cell" is 3 times in your question, "matrix" zero times. Please take your time to properly write your questions

Comment: Actually, matrix is in my question but sorry for not properly describing the issue. The underlying data is a 1935x582 matrix but I want to replace all cells of this matrix that show NaN by the value of the cell before. How would you do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is a cell of a matrix? elements? what happens when `i=1` has NaN values?

Comment: yes, i'm talking elements, sorry. I changed i to 2:1935 so that won't be an issue anymore (besides the fact that it replaces NaN by NaN if i=1 is also NaN...).

Comment: @Michael To clarify, "cell" has a very precise meaning in Matlab, different than a matrix entry. So you should say "matrix entries", not "matrix cells"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not have `NaN` in the first row, and remembering that [NaN is never equal to NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587351/why-does-replacing-nans-of-a-matrix-not-work-with-kk-nan-somenumber-where/38587604#38587604):

```
for ii=2:size(RSPB0916v05NEW5,1)%number of rows
    idx=find(isnan(RSPB0916v05NEW5(ii,:))); % find the index of NaNs
    RSPB0916v05NEW5(ii,indx)=RSPB0916v05NEW5(ii-1,indx); % replace them from the previous row
end
```

Note that if the first row has `NaN` values, you need to handle it separately.